# RedundantNameQualifier error when Running Resharper CLI inspect tool

Tags: .net-core, console-application, resharper, static-code-analysis, .net-core-2.0

I'm using Resharper inspect CLI tool for static code analysis(JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2018.3.1\InspectCode.exe) on a dotnet core 2.1 console application I've created.  Within the solution, there is a separate project which is just a package used in the console app.

Layout is as follows:

[image]

When I run the inspectCode.exe as follows:

```
JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2018.3.1\InspectCode.exe "AI.DL.Backup\AI.DL.Backup.csproj" /o:"CodeInspection_20222.xml" /profile:"AI.DL.Backup.sln.DotSettings"
```

I get the following issue:

[image]

Output xml report has the following:

```
<IssueType WikiUrl="https://www.jetbrains.com/resharperplatform/help?Keyword=RedundantNameQualifier" Severity="WARNING" Description="Redundant name qualifier" CategoryId="CodeRedundancy" Category="Redundancies in Code" Id="RedundantNameQualifier"/>

<Issue Message="Qualifier is redundant" Line="5" Offset="146-154" File="AI.DL.Backup\src\AI.DL.Backup\Startup.cs" TypeId="RedundantNameQualifier"/>
```

The problem seems to be that it cannot find the dll project referenced and is throwing code analysis error (code HAS been built already, so bin/obj folders exist with relevant dlls/packages required).

Ling 5 (as specified) is just the using statement for the separate package, which it cannot resolve and is deeming to be redundant.

```
using AI.DL.DocumentManagement;
using AI.DL.DocumentManagement.Stores;
```

Going by the generated XML report, I can see that it can't find the namespace within the separate package.  Why would this be?  Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Does it work if you invoke the tool on the solution file specifying the project you want to analyze? `JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2018.3.1\InspectCode.exe --project="AI.DL.Backup" --profile="AI.DL.Backup.sln.DotSettings" --output="CodeInspection_20222.xml" "AI.DL.Backup.sln"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue when I repointed the "inspect.exe" to my solution file instead of individual project!